# Implicit new and delete operator killing perfomance

Tags: c++, optimization, new-operator, profiler, delete-operator

I am running very sleepy to profile my application and its showing me that 25% and 23% of the time spent by my function is doing new and delete respectively. I don't understand where this is occurring. So can someone tell me where this is occurring in my code.

```
inline FixParser(fixmessage& tokenMap, const std::string& str) {
  static seperator sep_delim("\x01");
  static seperator sep_equal("=");
  static std::string error("ERROR: ");
  static FixKey fix_Key;
  static tokenizer token_equal(error);
  static tokenizer token_delim(error);
  static tokenizer::iterator itr;
  token_delim.assign(str, sep_delim);
  int key;
  try {
    for(tokenizer::iterator it = token_delim.begin(); 
        it != token_delim.end(); ++it) {
      token_equal.assign(*it, sep_equal);
      itr = token_equal.begin();
      key = boost::lexical_cast<int>(*itr);
      if(fix_Key.keys.find(key) == fix_Key.keys.end()) continue;
      ++itr;
      const std::string& value(*itr);
      tokenMap.insert(std::pair<int, std::string>(key, value));
    }
  } catch(boost::bad_lexical_cast &) {
    std::cerr << error << str << std::endl;
    return;
  }
}
```

[image: very sleepy results]

I beg forgiveness for the use of `static` they will be removed later and placed in a `struct`.

Comment: I can't see the image and I bet you can't neither.

Comment: Really guys, just open the image on a new tab. Or right click > "View Image" or whatever your browser gives you.

Comment: @Alex and Bitmap, open the image in a new tab and magnify it to 100% and it's perfectly clear. You're seeing an artifact of the way StackOverflow embeds the image.

Comment: You're running this on Release right? Not Debug?

Comment: @Seth Carnegie That's a huge Facepalm for me. I am running it in debug. I'll try release and see the difference.

Comment: @ahenderson yeah, in Debug `new` and `delete` are way slower because the debugger wants to make sure you don't have memory leaks.

Comment: @Seth Carnegie It seems that's not the issue. i got an improvement. now its 20% and 17%.

Comment: @ahenderson: after looking a bit into your function I am afraid to say that it's probably close to optimal given its constraints. It just turns out that apart from allocation and deallocation the functions are dead simple, thus exposing those operations as being the bottlenecks. I have offered work-around (avoiding memory allocation altogether) in my answer, I cannot think of anything better.

Comment: To find out where in your code it is coming from, just read the stack. It's got line numbers.

Comment: @Seth Carnegie Your 100% correct. the second time I compiled the project in release very sleepy was still pointing to a debug version. After realizing this I ran the release and it shows that the GUI is the bottleneck. The code is as optimal as it's going to get.

Comment: @ahenderson I have written it as an answer, you can accept it if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are testing the Release build, not the Debug version. Debug builds use different versions of `new` and `delete` that help detect memory leaks at the expense of speed, and Debug builds don't optimise much (if at all).

Answer (score 3):

One note: there are *lots* of strings being copied. Each string will incur a call to `new` to grab memory and `delete` to release it.

If performance is a premium and you have the ability to keep the copy of `str` around, you might want to use indexes instead. That is, having the tokens be pairs of indexes (begin, end) instead of full-blown strings. This is more error-prone obviously.

Also, `tokenMap` allocates one node per entry in the map, if you have a lot of entries, there will be a lot of nodes (and thus `new` to create them). You might want to use a `deque` instead, and sort the items once you're done, unless you really need what `map` offers (automatic deduplication).

---

Bikesheded version, removing most static variables (*could not help myself*):

```
inline FixParser(fixmessage& tokenMap, const std::string& str) {
  static seperator sep_delim("\x01");
  static seperator sep_equal("=");
  static FixKey const fix_Key;

  try {
    tokenizer token_delim(str, sep_delim);

    // avoid computing token_delim.end() at each iteration
    for(tokenizer::iterator it = token_delim.begin(), end = token_delim.end(); 
        it != end; ++it)
    {
      tokenizer token_equal(*it, sep_equal);

      tokenizer::iterator itr = token_equal.begin();
      int const key = boost::lexical_cast<int>(*itr);
      if(fix_Key.keys.find(key) == fix_Key.keys.end()) continue;

      ++itr;
      tokenMap.insert(std::make_pair(key, *itr));
    }
  } catch(boost::bad_lexical_cast &) {
    std::cerr << error << str << std::endl;
    return;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at `boost::lexical_cast`.  In its simplest form it simply uses streams.  It probably does a lot of allocations.

Comment: I don't think this is the case. I tried replacing `key = boost::lexical_cast<int>(*itr);` with a static value and it did not help.

Comment: Nope: the screenshot is sorted by inclusive performance and `boost::lexical_cast` does not appear (where the tokenizer does, a lot), so it's out of the equation for now. Also, since the OP is using Boost 1.47, he should have an optimized version.

Answer (score 0):

The statics may be the problem.  How many time are you calling the function `FixParser`?

Every time you call it the `token_delim` and `token_equal` objects have there assign methods called and if these are implemented like a vector assign then the memory backing the sequence will be destroyed and then allocated every time the `FixParser` function is called to assign the new entry.